# Twitter like counter

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Library/Framework used = Jquery+Bootstrap 4
I want to make a twitter like counter, but with two input fields, if the 2 input are valid, then post.
This is my code so far.

```js
$('.new_post_title').keyup(function() {
  var max_character = 15;
  var length_ = $(this).val().length;

  if (length_ > max_character) {
    $(".new_post_title_count").css('color', 'red');
    var character = length_;
    $('.new_post_title_count').text(character);
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(".new_post_title_count").css('color', 'black');
    var character = max_character - length_;
    $('.new_post_title_count').text(character);
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

$('.new_post_content').keyup(function() {
  var max_character = 10;
  var length_ = $(this).val().length;

  if (length_ > max_character) {
    $(".new_post_content_count").css('color', 'red');
    var character = length_;
    $('.new_post_content_count').text(character);
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(".new_post_content_count").css('color', 'black');
    var character = max_character - length_;
    $('.new_post_content_count').text(character);
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="new_post_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="new_post_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Title (Optional)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control new_post_title" placeholder="Make a title...">
            <span class="new_post_title_count"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Content</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control new_post_content" placeholder="Publish something...">
            <span class="new_post_content_count"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary new_post_button">Post</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, if i trick this code i can make the post without validating it, for the first input i put 20 chars and for the second i put 10 chars and the button is enable.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate check for enabling/disabling of the button, where you also take into account whether the other field is valid. Both need to be valid for the button to show, but in your code you only check the field that you're currently typing in.

```js
var titleLength = 0;
var titleMaxLength = 15;
var contentLength = 0;
var contentMaxLength = 10;

$('.new_post_title').keyup(function() {
  titleLength = $(this).val().length;
  if (titleLength > titleMaxLength) {
    $(".new_post_title_count").css('color','red');
    var character = titleLength;
    $('.new_post_title_count').text(character);
  } 
  else {
    $(".new_post_title_count").css('color','black');
    var character = titleMaxLength - titleLength;
    $('.new_post_title_count').text(character);
  }
  if (titleLength > titleMaxLength || contentLength > contentMaxLength) {
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else {
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

$('.new_post_content').keyup(function() {
  contentLength = $(this).val().length;
  if (contentLength > contentMaxLength) {
    $(".new_post_content_count").css('color','red');
    var character = contentLength;
    $('.new_post_content_count').text(character);
  } 
  else  {
    $(".new_post_content_count").css('color','black');
    var character = contentMaxLength - contentLength;
    $('.new_post_content_count').text(character);
  }
  if (titleLength > titleMaxLength || contentLength > contentMaxLength) {
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else {
    $('.new_post_button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="new_post_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="new_post_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Title (Optional)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control new_post_title" placeholder="Make a title...">
            <span class="new_post_title_count"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Content</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control new_post_content" placeholder="Publish something...">
            <span class="new_post_content_count"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary new_post_button">Post</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PERFECT !. Thanks vi5ion